# Android soft keyboard displays weirdly after calling onResume

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, onresume, soft-keyboard

I have an EditText that I manually control showing keyboard by below code:

```
private void showKeyboard(boolean show) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (show) {
        mAddNewEditText.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(mAddNewEditText, 0);
    } else {
        mAddNewEditText.clearFocus();
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAddNewEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

[image: Opened the keyboad]

I'll call implicit intent to gets a new image and when it goes back to activity, it wont show the soft keyboard. So I tried to show the keyboard onResume function as below:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAddNewEditText.isFocused()) {
        mAddNewEditText.post(
                () -> showKeyboard(true)
        );
    }
}
```

but it shows the keyboard like this which is different than normally showing the keyboard:

[image: soft keyboard shows weirdly]

I'm wondering what is the problem here. Is it because I'm using post method? without post I cannot show keyboard!

What have I tried:

- I tried to use without post which doesn't show the keyboard.
- I tried to call imm.showSoftInput(txtPassword, 0); which result the same.
- I tried mAddNewEditText.postDelayed method with 100 result the same.
- I tried putting android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" on Menifest result the same.

Note: I'm using Android emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the answer: 
in my styles.xml I had this code :

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

which caused the problem, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

put this line in your manifest inside activity

```
<aplication>
   <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
 </aplication>
```

Comment: I don't want to use adjustResize.

Comment: then use only stateHidden

Comment: ya I used stateHidden only. I found the cause of it, it was from android:windowFullscreen: true. not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try postDelayed(), delay 500 milliseconds or more. Ensure show keyboard after UI completed.

Comment: yes that worked too but for some strange reason. it was caused from <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> in my style file. Does that make sense? is it making windows full screen so the keyboard goes below it?